# is there a purrr related method to split a list into the multiple lists of smaller length?

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

Let me explain what I want using the code

```
taget_input <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
desired_output <- list(list(1,2,3), list(4,5,6), list(7,8,9))

# I wish there is a elegant function that passes this test
testthat::expect_equal(DESIRED_FUNCTION(taget_input, group_length=3), desired_output)
```

I wish there is a function like that. My google search did not yield any good result. Here's a rough implementation, but it's not elegant, and I was curious if there is any better way to do what I wanted to do

```
#' @param target_list list to split on
#' @param group_length length for each split 
group_list <- function(target_list, group_length) {
  len_of_list <- length(target_list)
  res <- list()
  i <- 1
  while(TRUE) {
    start <- (1 + group_length*(i-1))
    if(start > len_of_list) {
      break
    }
    end <- min((group_length + group_length*(i-1)), len_of_list)
    res[[i]] <- target_list[start:end]
    i <- i + 1
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: Essentially just `unname(split(taget_input, rep(1:3,3)))` isn't it?

Comment: OMG. @thelatemail you are right. I feel stupid now ;0